# multithreading with python ev3, join method doesnt work

Tags: python, multithreading, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I am running the code everything is working well but the join method doesnt work.

I have to wait for all the threads to finish to turn 90 degrees

I tried to use join method with a different code and not related to the ev3 robot, and its works but i dont understand why its not working with ev3.

**Error**: AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'join'

````py
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import (Motor, TouchSensor, ColorSensor,
                                 InfraredSensor, UltrasonicSensor, GyroSensor)
from pybricks.parameters import Port, Stop, Direction, Button, Color
from pybricks.tools import wait, StopWatch, DataLog
from pybricks.robotics import DriveBase
from pybricks.media.ev3dev import SoundFile, ImageFile
import threading

# This program requires LEGO EV3 MicroPython v2.0 or higher.
# Click "Open user guide" on the EV3 extension tab for more information.


# Create your objects here.
ev3 = EV3Brick()


left_motor = Motor(Port.B)
right_motor = Motor(Port.C)


robot = DriveBase(left_motor, right_motor, wheel_diameter=55.5, axle_track=104)

obstacle_sensor  = UltrasonicSensor(Port.S4)

obstacle_sensor_gyro = GyroSensor(Port.S3)
################################

def check_for_75_angle():
    while True:
        angle = obstacle_sensor_gyro.angle()
        print(angle)
        if angle > 75:
            robot.drive(0, 15)
            break
            


def check_for_90_angle():
    while True:
        angle = obstacle_sensor_gyro.angle()
        if angle == 90:
            break
            

def turn():
    robot.drive(0,80)
    


def main():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=check_for_75_angle)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=check_for_90_angle)
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=turn)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()




while True:
    cm = obstacle_sensor.distance() * 0.1

    if cm < 20:
        obstacle_sensor_gyro.reset_angle(0)

        main()
        print("Finished: 90 angle")

    else:
        robot.drive(20, 0)
    ```
````

Comment: It’s not obvious which line the error is referring to so please edit the _full_ text of the error message including traceback into your question, __as text__

Comment: I am sorry but i cant add the error right now. but its in "t1.join" line.